How to save/replace image on iOS using swift and PhotoKit
This seems like super easy job, but I struggle to replace image after its edit.
First dummy UI to pick image from gallery:
import SwiftUI
import Photos
import PhotosUI

struct ContentView: View {
    @State private var selectedImage: UIImage? = nil
    @State private var isPickerPresented: Bool = false

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            if let image = selectedImage {
                Image(uiImage: image)
                    .resizable()
                    .scaledToFit()
                    .frame(height: 300)
            } else {
                Text("No image selected")
            }

            Button(action: {
                isPickerPresented = true
            }) {
                Text("Pick a Photo")
            }

            Button(action: {
                selectedImage = editPhoto(selectedImage!)
            }) {
                Text("Apply Filter")
            }

            Button(action: {
                savePhoto(selectedImage!)
            }) {
                Text("Save Photo")
            }

            Button(action: {
                fetchPhotos().first.map { asset in
                    replacePhoto(asset: asset, with: selectedImage!)
                }
            }) {
                Text("Replace Photo")
            }
        }
        .onAppear {
            requestPhotoLibraryAccess()
        }
        .sheet(isPresented: $isPickerPresented) {
            PhotoPicker(selectedImage: $selectedImage)
        }
    }
}

struct PhotoPicker: UIViewControllerRepresentable {
    @Binding var selectedImage: UIImage?

    class Coordinator: NSObject, PHPickerViewControllerDelegate {
        var parent: PhotoPicker

        init(parent: PhotoPicker) {
            self.parent = parent
        }

        func picker(_ picker: PHPickerViewController, didFinishPicking results: [PHPickerResult]) {
            picker.dismiss(animated: true)
            guard let result = results.first else { return }

            if result.itemProvider.canLoadObject(ofClass: UIImage.self) {
                result.itemProvider.loadObject(ofClass: UIImage.self) { image, error in
                    DispatchQueue.main.async {
                        if let image = image as? UIImage {
                            self.parent.selectedImage = image
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

    func makeCoordinator() -> Coordinator {
        Coordinator(parent: self)
    }

    func makeUIViewController(context: Context) -> PHPickerViewController {
        var configuration = PHPickerConfiguration()
        configuration.selectionLimit = 1
        configuration.filter = .images

        let picker = PHPickerViewController(configuration: configuration)
        picker.delegate = context.coordinator
        return picker
    }

    func updateUIViewController(_ uiViewController: PHPickerViewController, context: Context) {
        // No updates required
    }
}

getting permission:
func requestPhotoLibraryAccess() {
    PHPhotoLibrary.requestAuthorization { status in
        switch status {
        case .authorized:
            print("Access granted")
        case .limited:
            print("Limited access granted")
        case .denied, .restricted:
            print("Access denied")
        case .notDetermined:
            print("Not determined yet")
        @unknown default:
            fatalError("Unhandled authorization status")
        }
    }
}

while having this in info.plist
<key>NSPhotoLibraryUsageDescription</key>
<string>We need access to your photos to allow you to edit them.</string>
<key>NSPhotoLibraryAddUsageDescription</key>
<string>We need access to save the edited photos back to your library.</string>

Still not so important ways how to get image/asset (for replace), edit photo
func fetchPhotos() -> [PHAsset] {
    var assets: [PHAsset] = []
    let fetchOptions = PHFetchOptions()
    fetchOptions.sortDescriptors = [NSSortDescriptor(key: "creationDate", ascending: false)]

    let fetchResult = PHAsset.fetchAssets(with: .image, options: fetchOptions)
    fetchResult.enumerateObjects { asset, _, _ in
        assets.append(asset)
    }
    return assets
}

func editPhoto(_ image: UIImage) -> UIImage? {
    return applyFilterWithFixedOrientation(
        image: image,
        filterName: "CIGaussianBlur",
        parameters: [kCIInputRadiusKey: 20.0]
    )
}

func applyFilterWithFixedOrientation(image: UIImage, filterName: String, parameters: [String: Any] = [:]) -> UIImage? {
    guard let ciImage = CIImage(image: image) else { return nil }

    // Create the filter
    let filter = CIFilter(name: filterName)
    filter?.setValue(ciImage, forKey: kCIInputImageKey)

    // Set additional parameters if provided
    for (key, value) in parameters {
        filter?.setValue(value, forKey: key)
    }

    // Get the output image
    if let outputImage = filter?.outputImage {
        let context = CIContext()
        if let cgImage = context.createCGImage(outputImage, from: outputImage.extent) {
            // Fix the orientation
            return UIImage(cgImage: cgImage, scale: image.scale, orientation: image.imageOrientation)
        }
    }
    return nil
}

func savePhoto(_ image: UIImage) {
    PHPhotoLibrary.shared().performChanges({
        PHAssetChangeRequest.creationRequestForAsset(from: image)
    }) { success, error in
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            if success {
                print("Photo saved successfully")
            } else {
                print("Failed to save photo: \(error?.localizedDescription ?? "unknown error")")
            }
        }
    }
}

This is probably the not working part:
func replacePhoto(asset: PHAsset, with image: UIImage) {
    PHPhotoLibrary.shared().performChanges({
        guard let contentEditingInput = getEditingInput(for: asset) else {
            print("Failed to retrieve editing input.")
            return
        }

        // Prepare editing output
        let editingOutput = PHContentEditingOutput(contentEditingInput: contentEditingInput)

        // Save new image data to the editing output's URL
        if let jpegData = image.jpegData(compressionQuality: 1.0) {
            try? jpegData.write(to: editingOutput.renderedContentURL, options: .atomic)
        }

        // Update the asset with the new editing output
        let request = PHAssetChangeRequest(for: asset)
        request.contentEditingOutput = editingOutput
    }) { success, error in
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            if success {
                print("Image replaced successfully.")
            } else {
                print("Failed to replace image: \(error?.localizedDescription ?? "Unknown error")")
            }
        }
    }
}

func getEditingInput(for asset: PHAsset) -> PHContentEditingInput? {
    let semaphore = DispatchSemaphore(value: 0)
    var editingInput: PHContentEditingInput?

    asset.requestContentEditingInput(with: nil) { input, _ in
        editingInput = input
        semaphore.signal()
    }

    semaphore.wait()
    return editingInput
}

Because when I try to replace the photo I've picked, I got this error:
Failed to replace image: The operation couldn’t be completed. (PHPhotosErrorDomain error 3303.)
What am I missing or why I cannot save it to original place?

Try printing error instead of error.localizedDescription and post the complete error in your question. That should provide a few more details.

Try modeling your code after an example that does work.

@HangarRash that doesn't seem to be helping at all:
Optional(Error Domain=PHPhotosErrorDomain Code=3303 "(null)")

@matt can you provide link or any other way how/where I can see working code, thx

I finally figured out the issue:

First of all, error 3303 occurs when adjustmentData of editingOutput are not set (even with dummy data).
Secondly, eventhough original image is HEIC, it seems that only JPEG is accepted, otherwise 3302 error appears.

Final simplified (for posting) code that works for me looks like this:
if let firstAsset = fetchPhotos().first {
            firstAsset.requestContentEditingInput(with: nil) { input, _ in
                if let input {
                    if let url = input.fullSizeImageURL {
                        let orientation = input.fullSizeImageOrientation
                        if let inputImage = CIImage(contentsOf: url, options: nil)?.oriented(forExifOrientation: orientation) {
                            // with gray filter
                            if let editedPhoto = inputImage.applyFilterWithFixedOrientation(filterName: "CIPhotoEffectMono") {
                                let editingOutput = PHContentEditingOutput(contentEditingInput: input)
                                let adjustmentData = PHAdjustmentData(formatIdentifier: "", formatVersion: "1.0", data: "".data(using: .utf8)!)

                                editingOutput.adjustmentData = adjustmentData // this is not optional, but it is not required to be set, otherwise 3303 error will be thrown

                                do {
//                                        try editedPhoto.heicData()?.write(to: editingOutput.renderedContentURL, options: .atomic)
                                    if let jpegData = editedPhoto.jpegData(compressionQuality: 1.0) { // JPEG is mandatory otherwise 3302 error will be thrown
                                        try jpegData.write(to: editingOutput.renderedContentURL, options: .atomic)
                                    }
                                } catch {
                                    print("Failed to write edited image: \(error.localizedDescription)")
                                }
                                if firstAsset.canPerform(.content) {
                                    print("Can perform content editing")
                                }
                                PHPhotoLibrary.shared().performChanges({
                                    let request = PHAssetChangeRequest(for: firstAsset)
                                    request.contentEditingOutput = editingOutput
                                }, completionHandler: {success, error in
                                    print("Success: \(success), Error: \(error?.localizedDescription ?? (success ? "" : "unknown error"))")
                                })
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }

